# How to fetch all emails from smtp server using PHP?

Tags: php, smtp, email

I am using PHP Codigniter, and i want to fetch all emails from mail server for particular user.

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI doesn't provide any functionality. But you might want to create your own library for this.

Start from here. [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php)

OR

You can use php imap class from here directly [enter link description here](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap).